# Фразеологизм и поговорка

Tags: фразеология

Скажите, пожалуйста, чем фразеологизм отличается от поговорки? В интернете не нашла ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если начинать от печки, то есть с определения понятий, то фразеологизмы и поговорки -  это разные вещи.

ФРАЗЕОЛОГИЧЕСКИЕ ОБОРОТЫ – это устойчивые сочетания слов, аналогичные словам по своей воспроизводимости в качестве готовых и целостных значимых единиц. Значение фразеологических оборотов не совпадает с лексическим значением слов-компонентов, то есть складывается не из суммы лексических значений слов, их составляющих, а представляет собой новый семантический обобщенный тип значения всего оборота в целом.

ПОГОВОРКИ – образные выражения, обороты речи, метко определяющие, отражающие какое-либо явление жизни. Поговорки не договаривают и не называют вещи, но весьма ясно намекают на них, причём в отличие от фразеологического оборота каждое слово в поговорке наделено своим собственным лексическим значением, а поговорка в целом может иметь как прямое, так и переносное значения. Поговорки, в отличие от фразеологизмов, не функционируют в речи как одна лексическая единица, их значение, как правило, складывается из суммы значений входящих в них слов.

Среди ученых, тем не менее, нет единства мнений по вопросу, являются ли поговорки разновидностью фразеологизмов. Например, В.В.Виноградов не относил пословицы к фразеологизмам, а Н.М.Шанский  предложил расширить классификацию фразеологизмов Виноградова и отнести к **фразеологическим выражениям** разнородные образования номинативного и коммуникативного характера - пословицы, поговорки, крылатые слова, изречения, устойчивые сочетания номинативного плана, например: *мир не без добрых людей, любви все возрасты покорны, после дождичка в четверг, сторонники мира*... Такие цитаты, пословицы, поговорки и ряд терминологических словосочетаний могут приобретать отдельные черты собственно фразеологизмов (воспроизводимость в одном и том же составе и намечающуюся метафоричность), например: *не в бровь, а в глаз; семь пятниц на неделе*.
В таком случае термины **фразеологизм** и **поговорка** вступают в отношения *гиперонима* (более широкого понятия) и *гипонима* (слова с более узким значением).